# Is there any reasonable cause for a LED driver to yield more voltage than it is labeled with?

Tags: led

I'm trying to make a light using an existing COB LED module of unknown health, and a new 300 mA constant current LED driver. I hooked up the LED to the LED driver and got 38V DC on the output instead of the max 20V it has printed on the case.

- Is this a definitive sign for a defect or is there a possible explanation for this (e.g. some LED specific "you start with a high voltage and ramp it down once current flows" strategy)?
- (Bonus:) If is this indeed an indication for a defect, how is an LED going to react to such a high voltage? I measured no voltage on the LED and it stayed dark. Is that expected or indication of a defect?

[image: The board]
[image: Casing]
[image: Lamp]
[image: Lamp backside]

Comment: Have you measured the voltage drop of the LED? Additionally, it's likely the LED driver is a constant current driver, and if the LED has failed open, the LED driver may be pushing the voltage very high (because it is trying to force a constant current through the LED).

Comment: Normally, repair questions are considered off-topic on EE.SE, but this one looks like it can be turned into a teachable moment, if you're interested in learning about the low-level details about LED drivers and are willing to provide additional information about your lamp. To start with, can you show us some good photographs of the board(s) in question?

Comment: The led driver is likely a constant current driver. Measuring it without a load will cause it to overdrive attempting to regulate the current when it cant. ***This is a false positive.*** The load voltage will be much lower, likely 18~20 volts @ 300 mA

Comment: @Dave  These photos don't cut it.  Nothing short of a schematic would do.

Comment: Can I just point out that the LED is labelled 240mA 16V.  So even if it was working, it might not work for very long at 300mA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LED drivers are usually constant current power supplies.  This one apparently puts out 300 mA, and is intended to work over the 6-20 V compliance range.

Since it is putting out more than that, the LED is probably presenting a open circuit.  It's no surprise that the voltage is above the range it promises to be able to put out 300 mA.  A ideal constant current supply would go to infinite voltage when presented with a open circuit.  This one apparently limits itself to 38 V.

Try connecting something like a 22 Ω power resistor to the output of the supply.  It should go to about (300 mA)(22 Ω) = 6.6 V.  It will also dissipate 2 W, so you don't want to hold it there with you fingers too long.

If the power supply works with the resistor test, then the LED or the wires to it are broken.

Comment: Interesting! I have a similar LED driver and I read 120VDC directly from the output. I was afraid it would kill my LED light tube, but it lit up the tube fine. Does the driver work sort of like a bench power supply where it automatically adjusts the voltage to maintain a constant current?